# By hitting space the cursor should move to next index in array

Tags: c++, arrays, input, space

I wrote a program of taking input from user in array. But if the user uses spaces instead of enter for entering next input, how do I move the cursor to next index when space is entered?
I tried the following code but doesnt seem to work

```
int* arr = new int[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cin >> arr[j];
            if (arr[j] == '32')
                arr[j] = '13';
        }
```

32 is ascii value for space and 13 id ascii value for enter. My user gives space separated intergers as input:

```
suppose n=5;

7 17 3 13 8
```

these are 5 inputs how do I make them different inputs for 5 indexes?

Comment: `if (arr[j] == '32')` => `if (arr[j] == ' ')` or `if (arr[j] == 32)`

Answer (score 2):

That **if** condition isn't required for this case. You can simply do this.

```
    int* arr = new int[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        cin >> arr[j];
    }
```

Comment: It's true. Formatted extraction should hoover up spaces just as it does newlines.

Comment: ... and [we can trivially verify that](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f86a0b04adca66a).

Comment: Actually it doesnot encounter spaces as new lines.. But I will try running it again